# How to find an object in an ArrayList by property

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How can I find an object, `Carnet`, in a `ArrayList<Carnet>` knowing its property `codeIsin`.

```
List<Carnet> listCarnet = carnetEJB.findAll();

public class Carnet {

    private String codeTitre;
    private String nomTitre;
    private String codeIsin;

    // Setters and getters

}
```

Comment: with `indexOf()`, provided your object overrides `equals()`.

Comment: the class Carnet is inside jar file i can't override equals()

Comment: If I were you I will find the source code from where ever and get it's equals and hashCode implemented. The only other alternative is to manually iterate over the Collection and check for member equality.

Comment: I would rather use a map instead of a list. If you often look for objects and performance is an issue, a sorted map might be better.
Implementing and using equal for this purpose is ugly in my point of view.

Comment: For Java 8 you can get the stream from the ArrayList and apply filter(e->e.codeIsIn.equals(...)) to it.

Answer (score 128):

In **Java8** you can use streams:

```
public static Carnet findByCodeIsIn(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsIn) {
    return listCarnet.stream().filter(carnet -> codeIsIn.equals(carnet.getCodeIsin())).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Additionally, in case you have many different objects (not only `Carnet`) or you want to find it by different properties (not only by `cideIsin`), you could build an utility class, to ecapsulate this logic in it:

```
public final class FindUtils {
    public static <T> T findByProperty(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
        return col.stream().filter(filter).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}

public final class CarnetUtils {
    public static Carnet findByCodeTitre(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeTitre) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> codeTitre.equals(carnet.getCodeTitre()));
    }

    public static Carnet findByNomTitre(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String nomTitre) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> nomTitre.equals(carnet.getNomTitre()));
    }

    public static Carnet findByCodeIsIn(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsin) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> codeIsin.equals(carnet.getCodeIsin()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 93):

You can't without an iteration.

**Option 1**

```
Carnet findCarnet(String codeIsIn) {
    for(Carnet carnet : listCarnet) {
        if(carnet.getCodeIsIn().equals(codeIsIn)) {
            return carnet;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Option 2**

Override the `equals()` method of `Carnet`.

**Option 3**

Storing your `List` as a `Map` instead, using `codeIsIn` as the key:

```
HashMap<String, Carnet> carnets = new HashMap<>();
// setting map
Carnet carnet = carnets.get(codeIsIn);
```

Comment: I dont get Option2. I override `equals()` and then do what?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am guessing use the `ArrayList.indexOf` method

Comment: You can overried equals() method which will make sure that when this particular field ONLY (codeIsin in this case) of one object equals to the same field in another object they consider equal. Then you can create an object with this field and the same value (same as in the object you are looking for) and search through the list as follows: listCarnet.get(listCarnet.indexOf(OBJECT YOU HAVE JUST CREATED)).

Answer (score 7):

If you use **Java 8** and if it is possible that your search returns null, you could try using the  [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class.

To find a carnet:

```
private final Optional<Carnet> findCarnet(Collection<Carnet> yourList, String codeIsin){
    // This stream will simply return any carnet that matches the filter. It will be wrapped in a Optional object.
    // If no carnets are matched, an "Optional.empty" item will be returned
    return yourList.stream().filter(c -> c.getCodeIsin().equals(codeIsin)).findAny();
}
```

Now a usage for it:

```
public void yourMethod(String codeIsin){
    List<Carnet> listCarnet = carnetEJB.findAll();

    Optional<Carnet> carnetFound = findCarnet(listCarnet, codeIsin);

    if(carnetFound.isPresent()){
        // You use this ".get()" method to actually get your carnet from the Optional object
        doSomething(carnetFound.get());
    }
    else{
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**To find an object in an ArrayList by the property, We can use a function like this:**

**To find all the objects with a specific codeIsIn:**

```
  public static List<Item> findBycodeIsin(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsIn) {
            
         return items.stream().filter(item -> codeIsIn.equals(item.getCodeIsIn()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
     }
```

**To find a Single item** (If the codeIsIn is unique for each object):

```
public static Carnet findByCodeIsIn(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsIn) {
    return listCarnet.stream().filter(carnet-> codeIsIn.equals(carnet.getCodeIsIn()))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
private User findUserByName(List<User> userList, final String name) {
    Optional<User> userOptional =
            FluentIterable.from(userList).firstMatch(new Predicate<User>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(@Nullable User input) {
                    return input.getName().equals(name);
                }
            });
    return userOptional.isPresent() ? userOptional.get() : null; // return user if found otherwise return null if user name don't exist in user list
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) in **Java 8** that returns the matched element if one exists in the list. If more than one elements are matched then the collector throws an IllegalArgumentException. A *null* is returned if there is no match.

```
Carnet carnet = listCarnet.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getCodeIsin().equals(wantedCodeIsin))
                    .collect(MoreCollectors.toOptional())
                    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following with Oleg answer, if you want to find **ALL** objects in a **List** filtered by a property, you could do something like:

```
//Search into a generic list ALL items with a generic property
public final class SearchTools {
       public static <T> List<T> findByProperty(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
           List<T> filteredList = (List<T>) col.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
           return filteredList;
     }

//Search in the list "listItems" ALL items of type "Item" with the specific property "iD_item=itemID"
public static final class ItemTools {
         public static List<Item> findByItemID(Collection<Item> listItems, String itemID) {
             return SearchTools.findByProperty(listItems, item -> itemID.equals(item.getiD_Item()));
         }
     }
}
```

and similarly if you want to filter **ALL** items in a **HashMap** with a certain Property

```
//Search into a MAP ALL items with a given property
public final class SearchTools {
       public static <T> HashMap<String,T> filterByProperty(HashMap<String,T> completeMap, Predicate<? super Map.Entry<String,T>> filter) {
           HashMap<String,T> filteredList = (HashMap<String,T>) completeMap.entrySet().stream()
                                .filter(filter)
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));
           return filteredList;
     }

     //Search into the MAP ALL items with specific properties
public static final class ItemTools {

        public static HashMap<String,Item> filterByParentID(HashMap<String,Item> mapItems, String parentID) {
            return SearchTools.filterByProperty(mapItems, mapItem -> parentID.equals(mapItem.getValue().getiD_Parent()));
        }

        public static HashMap<String,Item> filterBySciName(HashMap<String,Item> mapItems, String sciName) {
            return SearchTools.filterByProperty(mapItems, mapItem -> sciName.equals(mapItem.getValue().getSciName()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Predicate [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/)

Answer (score -1):

For finding objects which are meaningfully equal, you need to override `equals` and `hashcode` methods for the class. You can find a good tutorial here.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/28/significance-of-equals-and-hashcode/