# index -1 ArrayList and objects

Tags: java

```
public static void test(){
ArrayList<mainclass> zbor = new ArrayList<>();
mainclass l2c = null;

for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
l2c = new mainclass();
System.out.println("name");
l2c.name = user_input.nextLine();
System.out.println("surname");
l2c.sname = user_input.nextLine();

zbor.add(l2c);
}

System.out.println("===1====");
System.out.println(zbor);
System.out.println("===2====");
for (int i=0;i<zbor.size();i++)
{
System.out.println(zbor.get(i));    
}
int index_search = zbor.indexOf("max");
System.out.println(index_search);
System.out.println("===3====");

}
}

===== mainclass====
public class mainclass {

@Override
public String toString() {
return name + " "+ sname ;
}

String name;
String sname;


}
```

Why this happens?
When I am trying to see indexof string "max", it shows me -1 which is not true index should be 1. See pictures. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q69II.png)

Comment: Consider properly indenting your code if you would like people to try and read it.

Comment: Because `"max"` is a `String`, but `zbor` contains `mainclass` objects.  You're looking for a ruby in a mountain of rocks.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

> public int indexOf(Object o)
>
> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

As Dawood ibn Kareem said, your ArrayList is not a list of String but a list of mainclass objects. (You are using the wrong type in `indexOf()`)

Take a look at this question : [How to find an object in an ArrayList by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property)