# asking about non-primitives arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I have created `ArrayList`. How can i use this list to get method or attribute from the class. I tried but i could not reach any solution.

I tried to get into element in array list and get some attributes but i can't.

```
    public static void printOptions() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to our university!");
    System.out.println("Operations:");
    System.out.println("1- College");System.out.println("a) Number of Departments");System.out.println("b) Number of Courses");System.out.println("c) Number of Professors");System.out.println("d) Number of Students");System.out.println("e) Report");
    System.out.println("2- Department");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Number of Courses");System.out.println("c) Number of Students");System.out.println("d) Is Full");System.out.println("e) Enroll");System.out.println("f) Report");
    System.out.println("3- Course");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Number of Students");System.out.println("c) Assign");System.out.println("d) Is assigned");System.out.println("e) Professor Name");System.out.println("f) Is Full");System.out.println("g) Enroll");System.out.println("h) Report");
    System.out.println("4- Professor");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Display Salary");System.out.println("c) Get Raise");System.out.println("d) Report");
    System.out.println("5- Student");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Report");
    System.out.println("6- Quit");
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    printOptions() ;
      List<Department> departmentList;departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Course> courseList ;courseList = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Professor> proffList = new ArrayList<>() ;
      List<Student> studentList;studentList = new ArrayList<>() ;



      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
    int d = 0 , c = 0  , p = 0 , s=0 ; 
    College AinShams = new College() ; 
    while (true){

        String option = in.nextLine() ; 
        if(!"6".equals(option)) {
            if ("2a".equals(option)) { // Define new department
                System.out.println("Department Name:");
                String depName = in.nextLine() ; 
                System.out.println("Department Description:");
                String depDescripe = in.nextLine() ;
                System.out.println("Department Max Students:");
                int max_num = in.nextInt() ;
                in.nextLine() ; 
                Department Department_Name = new Department(depName, depDescripe, max_num); 

               //  departmentList.add(Department_Name);
                 departmentList.add(d, Department_Name);
                d++ ;
                AinShams.setDepart(departmentList);

            }

            else if ("4a".equalsIgnoreCase(option)) {//new proff
                System.out.println("Professor Firstname:");
                String firstName = in.nextLine() ;
                System.out.println("Professor Lastname:");
                String lastName = in.nextLine(); 
                System.out.println("Professor telephone:");
                String telephone = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Professor address:");
                String address = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Professor salary:");
                double salary = in.nextDouble() ;
                Professor proff = new Professor(firstName, lastName, telephone, address, salary); 
                proffList.add(p,proff) ;
                p++ ; 
                AinShams.setProf(proffList);
               }

            else if ("2e".equalsIgnoreCase(option)) {//add student in department
                System.out.println("Department:");
                String dep= in.nextLine() ;
                System.out.println("Student:");
                String stu= in.nextLine();   

              //  System.out.println(AinShams.getDepart());
              AinShams.getDepart().
                /*for (int i = 0; i < AinShams.getDepart().size(); i++) {
        }*/
            }
            System.out.println("============");
            System.out.println("Enter Operation");
            System.out.println("============");
        }else {break ;}


    }

}

}
```

In condition (2e), I need to get methods and attributes in class which I assigned in array List

Comment: `System.out.println(AinShams.getDepart().size());` or/and `System.out.println(AinShams.getDepart().get(i).getName());` without full code this is only a guess

Comment: This is awkward and hard to read: `List<Department> departmentList;departmentList = new ArrayList<>();` Why not initialize it directly? Like `List<Department> departmentList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AinShams.getDepart() is referring to an object which you defined as data type College:

```
College AinShams = new College();
```

The rest of the College code is not in this fragment so I cannot tell whether the .getDepart() method exists. Either way, the College is not an ArrayList.

If you want to reach the methods and fields of objects inside an ArrayList something like the following would work. As an example I take the ArrayList called departmentlist, and use the get() method to return the 0th element from that list. Assuming the 0th element of that class is an object of type Department, the .name asks for the name field (again, assuming this name variable exists in the Department class). The .getName() would be a better way to get the name value but requires you coding this method in the Department class.

```
departmentlist.get(0).name
departmentlist.get(0).getName()
```

By the way, consider reducing some of the "System.out.println()" clutter in the top of your code by formatting your output with the "\n" new line key. Try these two examples using 1 system.out.println call to print two lines of text:

```
System.out.println("Welcome to our university!" + "\n" + "Operations:");
System.out.println("Welcome to our university! \nOperations:");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a new student to a department. Your `College` class has other attributes like list of departments, professors, etc.

**Approach:**

You can get the Department object from the array list, by the department name (property) passed by the user in case-2e. Then use that object to insert new student to its student's list.

**Code:**

Your code can be something like below (Pardon any compilation error as I haven't used any IDE. Follow the approach):

```
String dept = in.nextLine();
Department department = AinShams.getDepart().stream().filter(department -> department.getName().contentEquals(dept)).limit(1);
department.getStudentList().add(new Student());
```

Follow the link for non-stream version:

[How to find an object in an ArrayList by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property)

**OR** Use the following method:

```
Department findDepartment(List<Department> deptList, String dept) {
    for(Department department : deptList) {
        if(department.getName().equals(dept)) {
            return department;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: actually you know what i mean but i don't know stream and filter how it work , i add in department method "isEnroll" it's assign student in department so i need to get department name i assign in operation (2a) in arrayList in college class  to compare this name by dept to use method enroll to assign student in department

Comment: I have added the non stream version as well. You can follow the link or take a look at the sample code (findDepartment method)