# How to search by attribute in a list? Java

Tags: java, list, oop

I have a program and it is reading commands from a file sent as an argument. For example, it read a command called `CreatePersonel U P001 Ali Poyraz 6` and created a staff member with this information. (`U = UnQualified Personal`, `P001 = ID`, `Ali = Name`, `Poyraz = Surname`, `6 = workhour`) After I create this personnel, I save them in a list. When the program reads a command like `ShowPersonnel P001`, how can I find the element with that ID? Thanks in advance. If you need, here is my code:

Driver Class:

```
import Employee.Employee;
import Employee.QualifiedEmployee;
import Employee.UnQualifiedEmployee;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int workhour;

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scan.nextLine();
            String[] datas = data.split("\\s+");
            int y = 0;
            try {
                while(datas[y] != null){
                    String command = datas[y];

                    switch(command){
                        case "CreatePersonel":
                            if(datas[y+1].equals("U")){
                                Employee newEmployee = new UnQualifiedEmployee(datas[y+2],datas[y+3],datas[y+4],workhour = Integer.parseInt(datas[y+5]));
                                employees.add(newEmployee);
                                System.out.println("Personal Created. ID: "+newEmployee.getId());
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                Employee newEmployee = new QualifiedEmployee(datas[y+2],datas[y+3],datas[y+4],datas[y+5]);
                                employees.add(newEmployee);
                                System.out.println("Personal Created. ID: "+newEmployee.getId());
                                break;
                            }

                        case "ShowPersonel":
                            String searchVal = datas[y+1];
                            System.out.println("ShowPersonel");         //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "CreateVehicle":
                            System.out.println("CreateVehicle");        //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "ShowVehicle":
                            System.out.println("ShowVehicle");          //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "AssignPersonel":
                            System.out.println("AssignPersonel");       //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "MoveToStartPoint":
                            System.out.println("MoveToStartPoint");     //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "TransferCargo":
                            System.out.println("TransferCargo");        //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "CanTransferCargo":
                            System.out.println("CanTransferCargo");     //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "UseFireArm":
                            System.out.println("UseFireArm");           //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "CanUseFireArm":
                            System.out.println("CanUseFireArm");        //Will be written...
                            break; 

                        case "Transport":
                            System.out.println("Transport");            //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "CanTransport":
                            System.out.println("CanTransport");         //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "EmergencyAction":
                            System.out.println("EmergencyAction");      //Will be written...
                            break;

                        case "CanEmergencyAction":
                            System.out.println("CanEmergencyAction");   //Will be written...
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ignored) {
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float sec = (end - start) / 1000F;
        System.out.println("Program executed in "+sec+" seconds.");
    }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
package Employee;

public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Employee(String id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void info(){
        System.out.println("Name: "+this.getName()+" Surname: "+this.getSurname()+" ID: "+this.getId()+" Type: Employee");
    }
}
```

UnQualifiedEmployee Class:

```
package Employee;

public class UnQualifiedEmployee extends Employee{
    int workHour;

    public UnQualifiedEmployee(String id, String name, String surname, int workHour) {
        super(id, name, surname);
        this.workHour = workHour;
    }

    public int getWorkHour() {
        return workHour;
    }

    public void setWorkHour(int workHour) {
        this.workHour = workHour;
    }

    @Override
    public void info() {
        System.out.println("Name: "+this.getName()+" Surname: "+this.getSurname()+" ID: "+this.getId()+" Type: UnQualified Employee");
    }
}
```

QuaifiedEmployee Class:

```
package Employee;

public class QualifiedEmployee extends Employee{
    private String lisanceNumber;

    public QualifiedEmployee(String id, String name, String surname, String lisanceNumber) {
        super(id, name, surname);
        this.lisanceNumber = lisanceNumber;
    }

    public String getLisanceNumber() {
        return lisanceNumber;
    }

    public void setLisanceNumber(String lisanceNumber) {
        this.lisanceNumber = lisanceNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void info() {
        System.out.println("Name: "+this.getName()+" Surname: "+this.getSurname()+" ID: "+this.getId()+" Type: Qualified Employee");
    }
}
```

I dont know if you need other classes in my project but if you need just tell me and I'll share.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find an object in an ArrayList by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question, you have a list with objects like (U = UnQualified Personal, P001 = ID, Ali = Name, Poyraz = Surname, 6 = workhour) and you get an element ShowPersonnel P001, where P001 is the id. You can iterate on your list and check if there is an element with that id.

For example:

employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("P001")).collect(toList())

Then you'll have a list with all elements with that id and if unique a list with one element only

Comment: yea thank you. But how can I access that list? What I mean is that I dont know how "employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("P001")).collect(toList())" works but after that, How can I print personel's info to the console where id is P001?

Comment: sorry for my late answer. you can just
employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("P001")).forEach(employee -> System.out.println(employee.toString()))

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend u make map with ID and position in the list. It will be faster to process than iterating through all items in the list.

But if you have not so much employees in the list, go for stream.filter. It will do his job good.