# get id passing name string in java object

Tags: java

I have class for user objects as follow:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }


 
    private ArrayList<User> userlist;
    private User user1;

   User user1 = new User("230", "cat");
                userlist.add(user1);

   User user2 = new User("100", "dog");
                userlist.add(user2);

   User user3 = new User("75", "other");
                userlist.add(user3);
```

Now, I'm trying to get the id (example I need to get 100 when I pass name dog)
and get 75 when I pass string other. any idea how to do that please?

Comment: Naive/easiest way: iterate through the list; check each element by comparing the result of its `getName` method with `"dog"`; if comparison is true use `getId` to get the id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find an object in an ArrayList by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stream api like that:

```
userlist.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getName().equals("dog"))
        .map(User::getId)
        .findAny();
```

or `foreach` cycle:

```
for(User user: userlist){
   if(user.getName().equals("dog")){
      System.out.println(user.getId());
   }
}
```