# How to get the latest records from the same element in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

How can we do it in Java? I've a 4 employee object, I see ssn is same in them, but I want to only get such records where version is latest.

```
public class MapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the latest Schema version
        Employee employee = Employee.builder().firstName("John").lastname("Do").email("john.doe@gmail.com").ssn(12345).version(1).build();
        Employee employee1 = Employee.builder().firstName("John").lastname("Doe").email("john.doe@hotmail").ssn(12345).version(2).build();

        Employee employee2 = Employee.builder().firstName("Jane").lastname("K").email("jane.k@gmail").ssn(45678).version(20).build();
        Employee employee3 = Employee.builder().firstName("Jane").lastname("Kerr").email("jane.kerr@gmail").ssn(45678).version(28).build();

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(employee);
        employees.add(employee1);
        employees.add(employee2);
        employees.add(employee3);
        
        // I want latest version employee object here here its - employees1 and employees3
        
    }
```

Employee.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private int version;
    private int ssn;
}
```

Comment: Well ... "Closed. This question needs details or clarity." There is your reason.

Comment: "How can we do it in Java?" => What is "it"? What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I've added details now, please guide

Comment: The edit makes it much clearer. Although you still have an undefined reference to something called "Responses".

Comment: @JeffCook please add (at least the necessary part) of the employee class. i guess you want to remove duplicate entries (where duplicate is everything with the same ssn), and only keep the latest "version". your question doesn't really make that clear. you can sort your list by SSN/version, and iterate through it, then delete everything that comes up more than once. Or you use a implementation of set and override the `add` method, to replace outdated versions.

Comment: It seem 12345 ssn has latest version = 2 and 45678 ssn has latest version=28, u need only these two records, ok

Comment: Sorry, but your question reads like it was written by a first day newbie. Have you done *any* prior research? This site is full of questions that deal with fetching objects from lists, based on different properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property

Comment: So even if the question would have been clear enough, it is obviously a DUP to one of many many similar questions asked before.

Comment: @GhostCat it's not a dup of the question you mentioned in the comment. It needs comparison to the properties in all the other  list entries, which that question doesn't do. I think this one should be reopened.

Comment: In other words, it needs some kind of `distinct` function on the list, but this distinct function needs to pick the correct entry, not just the first one.

Comment: @Andi - Can you some code, after sorting by ssn, how would you identify the latest version?

Comment: @JeffCook : first make a list of all existing distinct ssn, then loop threw all ssn to filter and sort your employees list and take first, add the result to a new result list

Comment: @JeffCook can you clarify what you mean by "latest"? Is it the highest version number, or the latest entry with the same ssn that is read from the list? Given your example, both methods give the same results employee1 and employee3. But what if employee2 had version number 29?

Comment: @Pra_A - Please take moment and read the question. version is property in Employee class, if SSN matches, get the latest version employee out of it

Comment: @k314159 That was just one example. You can easily find existing answers here that tell you how to filter out on one constraint on property X, to then do another filtering on another constraint on Y.

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this, but still can be make mature/refactor. I will try it out and will see if I can put another answer or make it more mature.

**Solution-1:**

```
Collection<Employee> values = employees.stream()
                .<Map<Integer, Employee>>collect(HashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put(e.getSsn(), e), Map::putAll)
                .values();
        System.out.println(values);
```

I see output like below:

```
[Employee(firstName=John, lastname=Doe, email=john.doe@hotmail, version=2, ssn=12345), 
Employee(firstName=Jane, lastname=Kerr, email=jane.kerr@gmail, version=28, ssn=45678)]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't pick the employee with the _highest version number_. Instead, it picks the employee that was last encountered in the list. Thus if you replace version 20 with 29 for employee2, you'll still get the same results with this answer, even though you would expect version 29 because that's higher than version 28.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
var ssnToEmployee = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
for (var emp: employees)
    ssnToEmployee.merge(emp.getSsn(), emp, (o, n) -> o.getSsn() > n.getSsn() ? o : n);
    
for (var emp: ssnToEmployee.values())
    System.out.println(emp);
```

Equivalently, you can use streams, in particular the version of [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) that takes a merge function:

```
var ssnToEmployee = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getSsn, e -> e, (o, n) -> o.getSsn() > n.getSsn() ? o : n);
```

(Note: the above doesn't keep the values in any particular sorted order. If you want to preserve the original order of your list, you can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.)

Comment: If I run this I am getting 
`Employee(firstName=John, lastname=Do, email=john.doe@gmail.com, version=1, ssn=12345)
Employee(firstName=John, lastname=Do, email=john.doe@gmail.com, version=1, ssn=12345)`

Comment: @JeffCook that doesn't sound possible, since ssn is the key in the map, and duplicate keys are not allowed. I will try to run it myself later on and see what went wrong.

Comment: @JeffCook I've corrected some syntax errors but the logic is still the same and produces the correct results as you can see at https://jdoodle.com/ia/nhn