# Find all objects in list that contain a certain field

Tags: java

I'm trying to find all the objects in a list of objects that contain a particular field name. For example

```
"list": [
  {
    "namesArray": [],
    "name": "Bob",
    "id": "12345",
  },
  {
    "namesArray": [
      "Jenny"
    ],
    "name": "Ned",
  },
  {
    "namesArray": [],
    "name": "Jane",
    "id": "gkggglg",
  }
 ]
```

The class looks like this:

```
class ListItem {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<String> namesArray; 
}
```

So basically I need to find all the objects that contain the field "id". Something like:

```
list.stream().filter(li -> li.equals("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've tried following this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526608/how-to-find-an-object-in-an-arraylist-by-property) and it isn't quite what I want. I don't care about the values of the id's, just whether or not the object has the field at all.

Comment: What exactly is `list` here? You've shown JSON, but we don't know what your object model looks like. Have you already parsed the JSON?

Comment: Yes JSON is already parsed. The list is the list of objects above. The list is named list.

Comment: How did you parse it? What *specifically* is held in that list?

Comment: It's literally just a list of objects as you can see above

Comment: Can you explain what the desired result looks like?

Comment: So a list where everything is an instance of just `java.lang.Object`? That seems very unlikely. It seems more likely that they're instances of *some specific type that you've created* (or perhaps a general one that comes with the JSON parser you're using), but which you haven't told us about. Please provide a [mcve], and read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions for how to ask better questions.

Comment: The desired result would be all the objects that have the field "id" in the object and no objects that don't contain "id"

Comment: Yes it's a list of OBJECTS @JonSkeet. It's seriously not that complicated. The specific type is made up by me. It's just a class.

Comment: "literally just a list of objects" parsers would return list of some kind of objects like like list of `List<JSONElement>` or `List<YourOwnClass>` (depending on parser). So without knowing what *kind* of object is held in the list we can't know about methods/API which is available to us which prevents us from giving you correct answer.

Comment: "The specific type is made up by me" - but you haven't told us *anything about it*. Why are you so reluctant to give us details? Do you not understand that *without specific details, we cannot help you*? I agree that it's probably not complicated - but we can't *guess* what your class looks like.

Comment: I mean, we *could* write answers based on wild guesses as to what your class looks like... followed by you probably saying "That doesn't work, because I don't have a method called `hasField`" (or whatever the answer uses). But that's not really a productive use of anyone's time...

Comment: @JonSkeet I added a model of what the class looks like. It's just a simple class with three fields in it.

Comment: Right, so now you've *finally* provided us the class - *all* the objects have a field called `id`, because that's in the class. Are you really interested in the objects that have a non-null value for the `id` field? If the JSON contained `"id": null` for one object, are you okay with that object not being included in the result? What about empty string values?

Comment: Hint: in the sample code you've given, `li -> li.equals("id")` is a lambda expression used to indicate whether or not the value should be included in the result. So *maybe* you want just `item -> item.id != null`...

Comment: Yes I want all the objects returned from JSON that contain the id field. It appears my JSON response doesn't include those that are null in the response. So all objects with a non-null id field.

Comment: Right - so that's just a predicate of `item -> item.id != null`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok that makes sense, do you know why it would return the error "Cannot find local variable 'li'"

Comment: @madmaxx01: Not without seeing the actual code you've got, no. Again, it's really pointless trying to make us guess. Maybe you've got `item -> li.id != null` for example... in which case no, you haven't got an `li` variable because you've used `item` as the lambda expression parameter. But that's *just* a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, we get your actual requirement:

> So all objects with a non-null id field.

It's easy to adapt the code you've already got using streams and a filter - you just need to change the predicate that's being passed to the [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) method. That predicate needs to return `true` for any value you want to be in the result, and `false` for any value you want to be discarded. So all you need is:

```java
var result = list
    .stream()
    .filter(item -> item.id != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, do you know why it would return the error "Cannot find local variable 'item"?

Comment: @madmaxx01: No, because I've run out of time to play guessing games. Provide a [mcve] and we may be able to help you. (Although I can't right now.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm stressed right now. It worked.