# Getting the product ID (integer) in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I've come across a problem where the user is supposed to input (by a Scanner) an ID of an object. It should be one of the 4-digited numbers I've put for each product that's on my "ff" list (either 1234 or 5678 or 9012 or 2345 or 7890). And if they enter a number (ID) that is not on the list, it should output a sentence telling the user they made a mistake.

Whatever I input on a console I get `"You've made a mistake! There's no product with such ID!"` as an output. Even if I input the number that IS on my list.

```
System.out.println("I'm displaying boots:\n");

List<FemaleFootwear> ff = new ArrayList<FemaleFootwear>();
ff.add(new FemaleFootwear(1234, "Boots 1", 180));
ff.add(new FemaleFootwear(5678, "Boots 2", 190));
ff.add(new FemaleFootwear(9012, "Boots 3", 150));
ff.add(new FemaleFootwear(3456, "Boots 4", 140));
ff.add(new FemaleFootwear(7890, "Boots 5", 220));
System.out.println(ff);

System.out.println("For shopping type 1, for going back to the menu type 2.");
int option = sc.nextInt();

if (option == 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the product ID:\n");
    int option2 = sc.nextInt();
    if (option2 == ff.indexOf(0)) {
        while (ff.contains(option2)){
        System.out.println("You've chosen the product " + option2);
        }
        }else {
            System.out.println("You've made a mistake! There's no product with such ID!");

    }
}
```

So for example, if I would type '1234', which is the product named 'Boots 1', the output should be "You've chosen the product 1234". But if I input a number that doesn't exist on the list (or a letter) it should show this error.

Comment: [How to find an object in an ArrayList by property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17526608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf(Object o)` requires that you give an actual Object contained in the list. In order to search for objects in the list (including with `.contains()`), you need to implement `equals` and `hashcode` on your class...

I think you meant `ff.get(0)`, not `ff.indexOf(0)`, and even still, you cannot compare an integer with an object in your list using `==`, or `.equals()`, as that would never match.

---

Instead, you need to search the list by their IDs, and you don't need a while loop.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the product ID:\n");
int option2 = sc.nextInt();
Optional<FemaleFootwear> search = ff.stream()
    .filter(footwear -> footwear.getID() == option2)
    .findFirst();
if (search.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("You've chosen the product " + option2);
} else {
    System.out.println("You've made a mistake! There's no product with such ID!");
}
```

Keep in mind that "4 digit numbers" that start with any leading zeroes, aren't "4 digit numbers" , so you might not want to use an integer to represent that.

Comment: An IntStream was shown in your previous question. It's similar. Any list of data can be made a Stream of objects